# Map SQL text array to Java String List in Spring data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have a text array as user_roles in my PostgreSQL database. I created a `List<String> userRoles` in my Entity. But `Could not determine type for: java.util.List` error appears. It works when I changed `List<String> userRoles` to `String[] userRoles`. 
How can I map a List to this array in Spring boot?

Comment: You may need to share more details with code and error stack.

Answer (score 0):

String[] strs = {"a", "b", "c"};

List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(strs));

Comment: I want to directly map SQL array column to my List in the entity class.